# Number of commuting pairs in p-group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G=GL_n ( \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}
)$. Consider the set $U$ of upper-triangular matrices of $G$ having
entries of $1$ on the diagonal. The set $U$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup
of $G$. I search to compute the number of commuting pairs in the
p-group $U$. It is well known that this number is $|U|·k(U)$ , where
$k(U)$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $U$. Then the question
is equivalent to determining the number of conjugacy classes of $U$.
Which of the two proposals is correct? and why:

- $k(U)$ is the index of its normalizer in $G$.
- $k(U)$ is given by [Higman
  Conjecture](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/pattern_groups9.pdf).

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: The second option does not give a precise formula for $k(U)$. But, as far as I know, Higman's conjecture is still open, as seems clear from the linked paper. As for the first option, do you mean to ask whether $[G:U] = k(U)$ or whether $[G:B] = k(U)$, where $B = N_{G}(U)$? When $n = 2$, neither of these options seems to hold, since $k(U) \leq |U|$ and $[G:B] > |U|$, so I am a little unclear what you mean to ask.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I mean in the first option that $k(U)=[G:N_{G}(U)]$ which is easy to calculate.

Comment: OK, but when $n = 2$, we have $[G:N_{G}(U)] = p+1,$ while $k(U) = p$, so the first option (with "it" $=N_{G}(U)$) does not hold for $n = 2$ (and for lots of other cases).

Comment: Yes thanks. But which of the two options is correct  to  compute the number of commuting pairs in U.

Comment: The number of commuting pairs in $U$ is $|U|k(U)$. I want to know
if $k(U)=[G:N_{G}(U)]$ or not. More precisely, is the number of commuting pairs in $U$ is $|U|.[G:N_{G}(U)]$?.

Comment: Geoff Robinson has said already in a previous comment that $k(U) = |G:N_G(U)|$ is false in general. In just computed another example. When $n=p=3$, we have $k(U)=11$ and $|G:N_G(U)| = 52$.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to write an answer. As I said in comments, Higman's conjecture seems still to be open, and does not, in any case, predict a precise formula for $k(U)$.

As for the other question, as clarified in comments, the question is intended to ask whether $k(U) = [G:B]$, where $B = N_{G}(U).$ I point out that when $n > 1$, it is never the case that $k(U) = [G:B].$

To do this, I note that $[G:B] \geq 1+|U|$, while it is clearly the case that $k(U) \leq |U|.$

The Sylow $p$-subgroup $U$ of $G$ has a conjugate $U^{x}$ with $U \cap U^{x} = 1$, 
(just take $U^{x}$ to be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of all lower unitriangular matrices). Then $B \cap B^{x}$ is a $p^{\prime}$-group since $B$ has only one Sylow $p$-subgroup. Hence 
$|BxB| = |BxBx^{-1}| = |B||xBx^{-1}|/|B \cap xBx^{-1}| \geq |U||B|$, so that $[G:B] \geq |U|$. But $[G:B]$ is coprime to $p$, so that $[G:B] \geq 1+|U| > |U| \geq k(U)$, as claimed.

Later edit: Quicker to say $[G:B] = 
\prod_{i=2}^{n} \frac{p^{n}-1}{p-1} \geq \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (p^{i}+1) > \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} p^{i} = |U|$.